# MATLAB installation in home folder

Tags: uninstall, directory, home-directory, matlab

Im a relatively new user on the ubuntu 14.04 OS and have little experience with the system.

Earlier this week I tried to install our all favorite matlab software package. Due to a confusion that I had, I changed the installation path from the default to the home directory....

I need some suggestions on how to delete this package from that directory. please any help is more than welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this problem has already been resolved since it looks a bit dated.

From the info. you've provided, I think you can simply just delete the directory in your Home manually. Install it correctly by running sudo ./install from the directory containing the install script (are you installing from a .iso file, or do you have a CD or an installation archive from Mathworks?). Then you can simply create a symbolic link to the new installation location, or add an alias in your .bashrc file with the new installation path (by default it should be /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/matlab ). Cheers!